# cannot call function into other function it giving me error in cal function at calculator(choice) where I am calling

Tags: python

The function cal is not calling calculator function giving me an error, I am trying to call calculator from cal function so that it will work.

```
def calculator(choice):
      if choice=='1':
         print(num1+num2)
      elif choice=='2':
         print(num1-num2)
      elif choice=='3':
          print(num1*num2)
      elif choice=='4':
          print(num1/num2)
        
def cal():
     print("Select operation.")
     print("1.Add")
     print("2.Subtract")
     print("3.Multiply")
     print("4.Divide")
     choice=input()
     num1= int(input())
     num2= int(input())   
     calculator(choice)

cal()
```

Output:

> Select operation. 1.Add 2.Subtract 3.Multiply 4.Divide 1 2 3 Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\atifm\Downloads\atif-089-A (1)\lab#2.py", line 24, in  cal() File "C:\Users\atifm\Downloads\atif-089-A (1)\lab#2.py", line 22, in cal calculator(choice) File "C:\Users\atifm\Downloads\atif-089-A (1)\lab#2.py", line 5, in calculator print(num1+num2) NameError: name 'num1' is not defined

Comment: How far does `cal()` get when you run it? Does it produce any errors?

Comment: it is working well but till  at line  at calculator(choice)

Comment: here is the output error

Comment: Select operation.
1.Add
2.Subtract
3.Multiply
4.Divide
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\atifm\Downloads\atif-089-A (1)\lab#2.py", line 24, in <module>
    cal()
  File "C:\Users\atifm\Downloads\atif-089-A (1)\lab#2.py", line 22, in cal
    calculator(choice)
  File "C:\Users\atifm\Downloads\atif-089-A (1)\lab#2.py", line 5, in calculator
    print(num1+num2)
NameError: name 'num1' is not defined

Comment: Ah, the variables in `cal()` are local to that function, so you will need to pass them into `calculator()`. Maybe something like `def calculator(choice, num1, num2):`?